# Select record using values from a previous COUNT() IN MYSQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I obtain a series of values that appear **only one time** in my database using COUNT in mysql that list below:

```
valueName 
---------
value1 
value2 
value3 
value4
```

I need a script that retrieves all records in a table where `valueName` **are not** the values listed in the initial count, and I need this two steps to run in a single script (doesn't matter how many parts it has).

I've got the script to obtain the list above like this:

```
SELECT field AS new_name  FROM table GROUP BY field HAVING COUNT(field) = 1;
```

And it works.

The problem is that I don't know how to work with the aggregated result of the first step. Maybe using some kind of function. Or loop (I don't think in SQL..).

I've tried different things like attaching a COUNT inside a WHERE clause and others but it doesn't work.

Please help!

Comment: Maybe you Tomas should read it better so it has been solved. It's so easy to criticize. The hard is to pay real attention.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT table.* FROM table 
JOIN 
   (SELECT field FROM table GROUP BY field HAVING COUNT(field) > 1) newtable 
ON 
   table.field = newtable.field;
```

This should work.

Answer (score 3):

Use a `join`:

```
select t.*
from table t join
     (SELECT field
      FROM table
      GROUP BY field
      HAVING COUNT(field) > 1
     ) filter
     on t.field = filter.field;
```

If you have a primary key in your table and an index on `table(field, pk)`, the following is probably faster:

```
select t.*
from table t
where exists (select 1
              from table t2
              where t2.field = t.field and t2.pk <> t.pk
             );
```

Comment: Sorry but this is not what I need. Maybe I need to clarify that the final table must have all the records that appear more than 1 time (that's why I made the COUNT). You first answer retrieves the records that only appear once in the table. I need the oposite. I've tried using the <> 1 operator but the results are not consistent.

Comment: @user3142418 . . . I did have the logic backwards.  The only reason that I could think for it not working is if `field` is `NULL`.